# build.gradle task to selectively copy dependencies based on filename?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to use kotlin for AWS lambda with Docker and it needs to copy dependencies like "kotlin-stdlib-{version}.jar" or else I get this error:

```json
{"errorMessage":"kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics","errorType":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","stackTrace":["Handler.handleRequest(Main.kt)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"],"cause":{"errorMessage":"kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics. Current classpath: file:/var/task/:file:/var/task/lib/kotlin-lambda-docker-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar","errorType":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException","stackTrace":[]}}
```

I was able to copy with this in build.gradle and get it to work:

```
tasks.register('saveDependencies', Copy) {
    configurations.each {
        if (it.isCanBeResolved()) {
            from it into "build/libs"
        }
    }
}
```

but this also includes classes, etc.

How do I just copy the dependencies starting with "kotlin" and ending in ".jar"?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with inclusion/exclusion as indicated [on the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_multiple_files_example). Something on the lines of this should do the trick:

```
tasks.register('saveDependencies', Copy) {
    configurations.each {
        if (it.isCanBeResolved()) {
            from it include("**/kotlin/**/*.jar") into "build/libs"
        }
    }
}
```